# How to disable access to router login page from Internet?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port

I just got a new router **Zyxel EX5601-T0**. Everything goes well, except that I discovered accidentally that the admin interface of my router can be accessed by anyone on the internet. This has never happened to me before (I used several routers before). Actually because of an indirect help from a subdomain (pointing to my **public IP-address**) that I discovered the problem. My problem is I tried to find where I can block the access to my router in the settings, but I can not find where to do it?? - I thought under the firewall, but there is no option for that except **Access Control** with an option to add a new **ACL Rule**!!

Any help or an idea is very appreciated

**Edit**: In the router setting there is no **Remote Managment** or **Remote Administration**
[image]

Comment: You question has been answered at https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/how-to-disable-access-to-the-router-login-page-from-internet.3805559/#post-22990596 where you posted yesterday ...

Comment: This is not Stack overflow!!!! why are you doing this??!!!! I really need help!!! - let's the community decide!!

Comment: How is StackOverflow any relevant here? You also don't need to spam punctuation. Did you verify the solution above? If so, describe why it failed or what else you need, please.

Comment: I am answering the solution above right now. Because I don't have this setting he sad. You will see my answer about a few seconds. I am not joking or spaming!!!

Comment: Please see my answer now.

Comment: Question: Are you accessing your public IP address _from the internet_ or still from the LAN?

Comment: with my public IP from the LAN I get the login page of my router. and it's the same from Internet (using public IP or my subdomain)......very scary !!!!

Comment: Add a password. Special characters, numbers and letters, upper and lower case, 16 characters will take thousands of years to brute force hack. My router allows me to turn off remote access but I have it on to be able to access.  No one has gotten in.

Comment: I did it yesterday (I have a pwd very very difficult ;)), but my problem is I have on another side a subdomain to my nextcloud pointing to my public IP and when I want to my nextcloud (using this subdomain) I get the login page of my router. It's very wrong and I have to find a solution.

Comment: Change to a router that allows you to disable remote access. Many do have this setting

Comment: Your Nextcloud is behind your router, how did you plan to access it from the internet? (The router would be blocking it!) I assume you added a port forwarding for the Nextcloud but set it up incorrectly to go to the router. Can you show a screenshot of all the port forwarding rules? Or at lest try to disable ALL port forwarding and see if it's still accessible.

Comment: @john....This is my problem. I just got this router (got fiber for 2 days ago). I doubt if my internet provider accepts??!!!! - Therefore I am trying to find a solution or any help!

Comment: I have an ubuntu server. the Nextcloud is on ubuntu serv.

Comment: What different is it what server Nextcloud is on? Generally, a router blocks access to anything under it. Right? So what settings did you change on the router to allow it to go through to the Nextcloud?

Comment: I made a port forwarding under NAT. I am starting to wonder that is is my big mistake.  Because I go this router for 2 days ago and I completely forgot to make a port forwarding like the old one. In addition to this, I was unable to access (public IP or my subdomain) from my phone (4g)!!! - But why is possible from LAN???!!!

Comment: So instead of actually addressing what I asked for you to answer/try, you're shifting away to another question. Is your router login page accessible from the outside internet? (Earlier you said that it is, but now it sounds like you're saying it is not.) *P.S. There is no need for all the drama and the truckload of question/exclamation marks...*

Comment: Sorry for the drama. It's just my way to say HELP. I was dumb to not try on another PC from outside my LAN or using 4g on my phone. I panicked. I am going to disturb you one more time, why I am getting the router login page when I try my public IP or my subdomain on my LAN?

Comment: That's expected. Your router knows its own public IP and when you access that from the LAN it serves you its own page (and it is not being blocked by the firewall since it comes from the LAN side, from where you're supposed to be able to access it.)

Comment: I understand for the public IP. what about the subdomain?

Comment: Subdomain is nothing more than a name for the IP it's pointing to, and it's pointing to your public IP. The DNS (to resolve the subdomain to the public IP) is done locally before the traffic is being sent, for the actual connection it's always using the IP addresses.

Comment: ok, thanks. If you make your comments as a official answer, I am going to accept it as a solution for my question. thanks again (you woke me up allerede when you sad about port forwarding).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information in the comments, the answer is that ***your router login page IS NOT accessible from outside over the internet***.

The reason you were able to access the router login page by going to the public IP was because you were on the LAN (from where login to the router login page is enabled.)

Despite the fact that you entered the public IP, it still reaches your router directly (and the router knows it comes from the LAN), it doesn't go out to the internet and then come back.

The same thing with the subdomain you accessed, which is just a name for the same public IP, so you again accessed the public IP/router directly from the LAN, which is why it was allowed.